# how to count values from a table and return true, only if the value is found 5 times using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, case, codeigniter-3

I am building a user like system using PHP and MySQL.

THIS IS MY TABLE

```
-------------- 
ID    value      
--------------- 
1       1           
2       0           
3       1
4       1
5       1
6       0
```

I'm trying to write a mysql query in php, that only displays total value count, if the total value count is greater than 5. i.e only return the query as true if there are more than 5 records found in the table.

Can someone please help me? I've tried many things.

This is my code i have tried so far

```
 $query = "  SELECT COUNT(value) AS value,
                    CASE
                    WHEN value > 0 THEN value ELSE 0 END
                    FROM users
            ";

 $query = $this->db->query($query);

 $query->result_array();

 if ($query->num_rows() > 0){

     echo "more than 5 records are found";

 }
```

THANKS

**(EDIT - To make the question clearer)**

So if we look at the table below (TABLE 1), value = 1 is found 6 times in the table. So the query should return true. This is because I am trying to count all values, where value = 1, and not value = 0. And I only want to return the query, if value = 1 is found 5 times or more.

```
TABLE 1 
-------------- 
ID    value      
-------------- 
1       1           
2       0           
3       1
4       1
5       1
6       0  
7       1
8       1
```

If we look at TABLE 2 below, value = 1 is only found 2 times in that table. So we return the query as false, because we need value = 1 to be found in the table more than 5 times to return true.

```
TABLE 2 
-------------- 
ID    value      
-------------- 
1       1           
2       0           
3       1
4       0
5       0
6       0  
7       0
8       0
```

I'd like to make this happen in the query and not using if statements outside the query using php. `ie, if($results > 5) { return true}`

THANKS

Comment: This is unclear, do you want to show results if there's more than 5 rows or do you want to show rows where `value` is bigger than 5 ?

Comment: where there are more than 5 results found in the table. My code is confusing

Comment: I know that  `value > 1 THEN value ELSE 0 END` only counts value where value = 1 and not 0. But but what do I do if i want the query only return true if 5 or more values are found

Comment: what do you want? the sum of values from column value?

Comment: why not use sum instead and if sum>=5 then return true

Comment: What I want is, find all the values in the table where value = 1. BUT if value = 1, five times, then I'd like to return some results from the query. If value = 1, is found only 4 times or less, I'd like the query to return nothing

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

You can use `count_all` to get the count and then get user records

```
$count = $this->db->count_all('users');

if ($count > 5)
{
  $query = $this->db->get('users');
  $records = $query->result_array();
  print_r($records);
}
```

Comment: What if 5 values are found?

Comment: @JustBaron its pretty understandable there, use `>=`

Comment: Ah, the OP question differs from the OPs comments. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You could use following query to get data if there are 5 or more than 5 records exists

```
select *
from users u
where (
  select count(*)
  from users
) >= 5
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3ae25/2)

Here is another [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0916d/2) if table has less than 5 rows

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the sum of values in the column value you can use this.

```
    $data = $this->db->get('users')->result_array();

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $num_value[] = $row['value'];
    }
    $num_value = array_sum($num_value);
    if($num_value > 5){
        echo 'value is more than 5';
    }
    else{
        echo 'value is equal or less than 5';
    }
```